# Error | Failed to generate a seed from SecureRandom within 3 seconds. Not enough entrophy?

Tags: server, java, minecraft, vps

Ubuntu Server 16.04 64 bit running on an OVH VPS
Java JRE 8 u91 64 bit

I'm using an OVH VPS server to run a BungeeCord Spigot Minecraft server network. When I run the BungeeCord.jar file, it starts up successfully then prints this error message at the end:

"Failed to generate a seed from SecureRandom within 3 seconds. Not enough entrophy?"

I've made a post on the Spigot forums, but haven't really gotten any replies. I'm asking here because I don't believe it's an issue directly related to Spigot. I've done some research and haven't been able to find much, just a few other reports from people who get the error in Spigot and other applications.

Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because since the `/dev/urandom` and `/dev/random` are only files which get filled constantly it seems more that this is a responsibility of the developers of `Spigot` to code in a way which at least not trying to take out more than is available in those files or invent a way to take out what is there and wait till you created enough entropy again by using your computer to take out more.

Comment: A problem with generating entropy should be handled by the developer of the software not the distribution it runs on.  OpenSSL for example could just say "We don't have enough entropy.  I'm going to error out", but they don't...  because they're developers.

Answer (score 4):

Installing `rng-tools` appears to have fixed the issue.